# Did the same "John" write the fourth gospel and Revelation?

Tags: john, revelation, authorship

By John, I mean the author of the *Gospel* of John (whom I believe to be the Apostle John, the beloved disciple: cf. John 21:22).

Anecdotally speaking, in my lay opinion, the same (I would say artfully) **simple** Greek is consistent throughout both, for example (almost a certain 'innocence' to it).

### Question

What are some *internal* lingustic/literary arguments for and against the John who wrote the Gospel of John and and the John who wrote Revelation being one and the same?

P.S. For the purposes of the question, 1st and 2nd John may also be referenced as 'internal' evidence, if they are found to be relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I understand the greek of Revelation is "horrible" suggesting it was written by someone who attended GSL night classes. The gospel is textbook greek but with prominent Hebraisms.

Comment: It seems like you might want to add the authorship of the epistles as well but that's up to you.

Comment: Revelation defies thorough awareness of the Old Testament, I can tell you that much. And as such, is permeated with 'hebraisms.' I'd rather not deal with the Epistles for now, unless they are found relevant. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: "defies" or "displays"? By hebraisms I mean writing greek but with hebrew conventions, such as beginning a sentence with "de" ("but") and not meaning "but". It is a prominent stylistic feature that I don't think is in evidence in Revelation. Caveat: All this is "if memory serves"!

Comment: 'Defies' as in 'tells of;' and by Hebraism a much wider sense is meant, i.e. inclusive of Hebraistic thought as well. I'm not quite sure that the usage of δε you describe is unique to New Testament or translation Greek, though..

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "belies"?:  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defies  But memory just kicked in... he begins sentences with KAI which he just uses as a paragraph marker, which is apparently a hebraism (usage #1): https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Hebraism

Comment: Off topic, but I think 'defies' carries this meaning in a certain context; e.g. 'your demeanor defies a certain apathy.' I could be wrong, obviously. Yes, this usage of *kai* is definitely a Hebraism.

Comment: The Gospel according to John is an historic narrative. The Apocalypse is one continuous vision of breathtaking scope, interweaving spiritual allusions from many of the prophets and expressing the whole in a poetic form. They are very different forms of writing, but internal evidence shows they are written by the same person.

Comment: Thanks, Nigel, but I need that in the form of an answer, with that internal evidence, if you can please.

Answer (score 1):

One gigantic correlation between the Gospel of John and Revelation is John's (Disciple John's) record of Jesus's encounter with John the Baptist.

John 1:29, 35-36

> ...
>
> on the morrow John seeth Jesus coming unto him, and saith, **'Lo, the Lamb of God,** who is taking away the sin of the world;
>
> ...
>
> On the morrow, again, John was standing, and two of his disciples,
>
> and having looked on Jesus walking, he saith, **'Lo, the Lamb of God;**'
>
> ...

(Disciple) John thought this was important enough to record while all the other disciples left it out, and this imagery permeates Revelation.

Revelation 5:6, 8

> ...
>
> and I saw, and lo, in the midst of the throne, and of the four living creatures, and in the midst of the elders, a **Lamb** hath stood as it had been slain, having seven horns and seven eyes, which are the Seven Spirits of God, which are sent to all the earth,
>
> ...
>
> And when he took the scroll, the four living creatures and the twenty-four elders fell before the **Lamb**, having each one harps and golden vials full of perfumes, which are the prayers of the saints,

Revelation 7:14

> ...
>
> and I have said to him, 'Sir, thou hast known;' and he said to me, 'These are those who are coming out of the great tribulation, and they did wash their robes, and they made their robes white in the blood of the **Lamb**;
>
> ...

I just picked three examples but there are many more references to the Lamb in Revelation.

Comment: Though not constituting a sufficiently exhaustive answer, this is definitely one of the better points of correlation to be considered—thank you for your input! +1

Comment: The parallel is not present in the Greek: ἀμνός in the Gospel; ἀρνίον in Revelation.

Comment: That is true. ἀμνός is more like a sacrificial lamb, ἀρνίον is more like a little lamb - a lamby.

Comment: The difference could be explained as highly symbolic vision being exaggerated in many ways, but the difference is quite noteworthy.